# PyTorch equivalent function for tfa.image.transform

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, tensorflow-addons

I want to perform an image transformation using a transformation matrix in PyTorch. My previous code was implemented in TensorFlow, so I wonder if there is any PyTorch equivalent function for [tfa.image.transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/image/transform) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projective image transformations can be done using kornia library's `kornia.geometry.transform.warp_affine` function. The API maynot be a drop in replacement of tfa.image.transform. For details refer https://kornia.readthedocs.io/en/latest/geometry.transform.html#kornia-geometry-transform

Below is the image from kornia transformation.

[image: Affine transformation from kornia]

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for [`torch.nn.functional.grid_sample`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.grid_sample.html) to sample an image (or a 2D feature map) according to new spatial coordinates. When used in conjunction with [`torch.nn.functional.affine_grid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.affine_grid.html) performs an affine spatial transformation of the input image / feature map.